# Python imaplib: get the first unread email

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, imaplib

I am running into a problem because when I use:

```
_, search = server.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
```

the search method returns all the unread messages... but I want it to just read the first unread message because otherwise the rest of the code makes no sense. Is this possible? So if i call the method again and again i want it to just return the next unread message and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you eventually plan to read all the messages anyway, looping over the ones which are currently unread is more economical than searching again after each message.

```py
_, search = server.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
for num in search[0].split():
   result, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
   msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
   whatever(msg)
```

If you genuinely want to quit after one message, you can quit the `for` loop with `break` after processing one message. Or rewrite the code to only process the first one:

```py
_, search = server.search(None, 'UNSEEN')
result, data = M.fetch(search[0].split()[0], '(RFC822)')
msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
whatever(msg)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Already had it similar to the first solution but got something else wrong... but your solution gave me the right hint ;)